# Lottie Android Studio Error Appcompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, lottie

when implementing lottie, it tells me this error in the appcompat. When I take out the lottie, it works perfectly.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kevinladelfa.life"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.8.0'
}
```

-

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{

        url "https://maven.google.com"

    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: try using `api 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'`

Comment: That's the one I'm using

Comment: use `api` instead of `implementation`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix a Lottie error in Android Studio - 'Error:Execution failed for task' java.lang.RuntimeException \[...\] unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672735/how-to-fix-a-lottie-error-in-android-studio-errorexecution-failed-for-task)

Answer (score 0):

Multidex is not enabled. Follow below steps to turn this on.
Step 1: Add this in module dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Step 2: Add this under default config

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Step 3: Add this in manifest under application tag

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
```

Then clean and rebuild.