# How to fix a Lottie error in Android Studio - 'Error:Execution failed for task' java.lang.RuntimeException [...] unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, lottie

When implementing a Lottie animation, it tells me there is an error in the appcompat. When I take out the Lottie animation, it works perfectly.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kevinladelfa.life"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.8.0'
}
```

- 

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{

        url "https://maven.google.com"

    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: may be problem of firebase. check [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1033).

Comment: Check "Build" tab you can see all errors and warnings there.

Comment: change version to 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Try "implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.1.2'", because that seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

just do the suggested updates in the build and it will work fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).